# Updating ui:defined form content from Master template (JSF & Primefaces)

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am having a little trouble with my web-app, essentially I keep getting an warning message:

> INFO: Cannot find component with identifier "formName" in view.

I know why this is happening, but I just need to determine if their is a fix/better solution.

Basically I have a master template file that contains a number of `<p:dialog>` components, which have various CRUD capabilities. When a user interacts with these components I use the inbuilt primefaces 'update' function to ajaxically update the various forms/components in the `<ui:defined>` page(s). However, because of the layout the JSF web-app (i.e. Master template and ui:defined web pages) and the fact that I have defined these components in the Master template file, it means that the update-able forms/components are not necessarily in the current view and throwing the warning message above.

For Example:

If I had my Master Template file: master.xhtml with a component called  <`p:dialog id="componentA" />`. And then I had page1.xhtml with a `<h:form id=page1Form/>` and similarly I have a page2.xhtml with `<h:form id=page2Form/>`, which both contained information provided by a sessionscoped backing bean, what would be the best method to ensure that these forms are updated if a CRUD operation occurs using componentA? At the moment I am simply using  <`p:dialog id="componentA" update="page1Form, page2Form" />` but because only page1 or page2 are is in the view, Tomcat spits out the above message. So is it possible to dynamically specify the forms/components to update dependant on the page I am on, or do I have to specify componentA on every `<ui:define>` page (which would be lots of repeating html/code and not particularly manageable) or is there a method to update all forms/components in the current view? Or is what I am doing correct and I should just turn off development mode in my web.xml to cease the messages?

Cheers

Ally

Comment: Can you pull up h:form to place it around ui:insert? This way forms would be a static part of your page and always there.

Comment: I think I can use the ui:param tag to dynamically set the forms/components to update depending on which page you're on.

Comment: Sounds good if it fits in your structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to confirm, if anyone stumbles upon this thread. I managed to fix my above  problem by using the `<ui:param name="paramName" value:"a value"/>` value.

Essentially in your master template file specify your component like you would i.e.

```
<p:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{someBean.doSomeStuff()}"
update="#{paramName}" />
```

Then in your `<ui:composition>` page you simply state param name and its value:

```
<ui:param name="paramName" value="someForm someOtherForm"/>
```

jobs a goodun!