# JSF Cannot find component with identifier , template and cie

Tags: templates, jsf, rendering, updates, identifier

EDIT :  another solution [Updating ui:defined form content from Master template (JSF & Primefaces)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9263193/updating-uidefined-form-content-from-master-template-jsf-primefaces)

In the first place, sorry for my english, I am one of these damn mono laguage french.

I have this classic error : *javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot find component with identifier ":formWaitingList" referenced from "formInscription:validerButton"*.

I know why this is happening but I don't know how to fix it.

I have a connexion form in the footer. I want to update a commandButton rendered in the page **rankMe.xhtml**. This page define the ui:composition "content" of the **template.xhtml**.
When I am on the page with the commandbutton i have no error and the rendering work perfectly. But when i am on another page like **index.xhtml** (whitch define the content of the **template.xhtml** too), Glassfish throw this exception, and I guess it is totaly standard cause the other content (**rankMe.xhtml**) is not load into the actual view.

How can I avoid this exception ? I could duplicate my commandbutton in all page and hide if the user is not on the actual rankMe.xhtml page but it's not a clean way too me.

Thanks

Here the code :

**template.xhtml :**

```
<h:body>
    <ui:insert name="content" >
    </ui:insert>

    <ui:insert name="footer" >
         <ui:include src="../template/footer.xhtml"></ui:include>
    </ui:insert>
</h:body>
```

**footer.xhtml :**

```
<h:body>
    <h:form id="formInscription">
          <p:commandButton id="validerButton" update=":formWaitingList" ajax="true"/> 
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

**index.xhtml:**

```
<h:body>
    <ui:composition template="/template/template.xhtml">
        <ui:define  name="content">
            Lorem ipsum ...
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>
```

**rankMe.xhtml :**

```
<h:body>
    <ui:composition template="/template/template.xhtml">
        <ui:define id="rankMe" name="content">
             <h:form id="formWaitingList">
                <h:commandButton id="Join"  
                                 rendered="#{connexion.connected}" 
                                 value="Join"/>
            </h:form>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>
```

Comment: Oh seems like the topic was already posted : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9263193/updating-uidefined-form-content-from-master-template-jsf-primefaces

Answer (score 1):

Two very simple solutions come to mind:
One solution would be to wrap your content part in an `p:outputPanel` and update it instead of your `formWaitingList`:

```
<p:outputPanel id="globalPanel>
  <ui:define  name="content">
        Lorem ipsum ...
  </ui:define>
</p:outputPanel>
```

Second solution would be to duplicate your `p:commandButton` just two times in the same **footer.xhtml** with different `rendered` values:

```
<p:commandButton id="validerButton" update=":formWaitingList" ajax="true" rendered="#{conditionIfYouAreInTheRankMeView}"/>
<p:commandButton id="validerButtonBis" update="otherThingYouWantToUpdateOrEvenNoUpdate" ajax="true" rendered="#{conditionIfYouAreNotInTheRankMeView}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip but it's still kind of messy, I'm searching for a real solution, except it doesn't exist . Plus, if you add an output panel here,imo it's doesn't change anything, I guess you mean wrap the <ui:composition template="/template/template.xhtml"> with outputPanel ? Maybe I failed in my explanation

Comment: No, I really mean, wrap the `<ui:define  name="content">` in an outputPanel. Now what about the second solution ? I think it's very useful

Comment: the second solution seems correct but it don't seem very  
rigorous. I would like something solid and adaptable witch follow a strict template with footer content and header and not a mixte thing.

Comment: of course it's. The only different thing here, is that the footer is customizable, it depends on used view

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9263193/updating-uidefined-form-content-from-master-template-jsf-primefaces sounds like a nice solution